# Minimal Artnet setup

Tags: dmx512

We have to expand a DMX512 installation and it looks like Artnet would be a good fit. We'll be using a commercial Artnet -> DMX (or -> SPI) receiver that implements Artnet4.

This a very simple, self-contained installation with just two devices, a controller (we build) and the decoder. We'll generate the Artnet data locally, using a micro or a PC. We have the protocol in hand, and DMX experience.

Question is, do we need to implement the entire Artnet poll, auto-IP etc or can we just assign fixed addresses and start shipping Artnet packets down the wire to the assigned UDP port?

Comment: What does [the specification](https://art-net.org.uk/resources/art-net-specification/) have to say about it? This is more a question about protocol and software than electrical engineering.

Comment: @JYelton - I have the read protocol spec and as far as I can tell it says nothing about this. I asked this question here because it's one of two Stack sites that have Artnet questions posted and answered, so I assumed there are users familiar with it. If you know of a better site, please let me know

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a good suggestion (hence why I didn't vote to close). I tried to see if Artistic License/ArtNet has some sort of active forum but did not find one. I am also a DMX/ArtNet user, but I don't know enough about it to assist.

Comment: @JYelton - I also searched for a forum etc and came here only after failing to find any better place. I may try Network Engineering, but it doesn't seem any more on-topic there.